# Emacs: Switching Between Buffers with the Same Name but in Different Directories

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, buffer, switch-statement, ido-mode

I have two files with the same name but in different directories:

```
apples/main.cpp
oranges/main.cpp
```

I open them in one emacs window via `emacs apples/main.cpp oranges/main.cpp`

When I use `C-x b` to switch between these two buffers, the buffer names are "main.cpp" and "main.cpp<2>". I would love to be able to see the full path of these two files when switching buffers, so that I may disambiguate between the apples and the oranges version. Is there a way to do this?

One way could be to modify whatever code generates the <2> after the second main.cpp when Emacs detects that a buffer with that name is already open. However, I couldn't find how to do this.

Comment: arghghghgh! I wrote an elisp function to do this, but it's at work and I don't remember how I did it. If you don't have an answer by monday, email me.

Comment: Looks like [uniquify](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/uniquify) provided in the answer below gets the job done perfectly.

Comment: Yep. My elisp function actually uniquifies the buffer by the `bzr` branch I'm in, which is nice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [uniquify](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/uniquify). I use it like that:

```
(require 'uniquify)
(setq uniquify-buffer-name-style 'forward)
```

Comment: Here's are some other [uniquify settings, which you might also like to try](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/init-uniquify.el).

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on Tomasz's answer.

There are other options for uniquify-buffer-name-style, besides *forward*, that you may consider:

Files /foo/bar/mumble/name and /baz/quux/mumble/name would have the following buffer names in the various styles:

```
forward        bar/mumble/name  quux/mumble/name
reverse        name\mumble\bar  name\mumble\quux
post-forward   name|bar/mumble  name|quux/mumble
post-forward-angle-brackets   name<bar/mumble>  name<quux/mumble>
```

If you want to strip common directory suffixes of conflicting files, add the line below to your emacs init file.

(setq uniquify-strip-common-suffix t)

Now, if you open /a1/b/c/d and /a2/b/c/d, the buffer names will say
"d|a1" and "d|a2" instead of "d|a1/b/c" and "d|a2/b/c".

Answer (score 1):

Use [lusty explorer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/lusty-explorer.el). Configure it with:

```
(require 'lusty-explorer)

;; Override the normal file-opening and buffer switching.
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'lusty-file-explorer)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x b")   'lusty-buffer-explorer))
```