# Showing file path during buffer switching in rails project in emacs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs

Im using Emacs with Ruby Electric and the Rinari extension for doing Rails development and ISwitchB for buffer switching.
In Rails it often happens that we have two files with the same name, like for example _form.html.erb, for different views. When switching buffers using C-x b, i see the filename but not the path to which the file belongs, so its not immediately apparent which one i want. Other editiors for example Sublime Text show that, but i want to stick with Emacs :)
Is there a way to show the path of the file too while switching buffers ?

Thank You

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs: Switching Between Buffers with the Same Name but in Different Directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607794/emacs-switching-between-buffers-with-the-same-name-but-in-different-directories) and [Emacs navigation between files with same names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040074/emacs-navigation-between-files-with-same-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the following to my .emacs

```
(require 'uniquify)
(setq uniquify-buffer-name-style 'forward)
```